# Calling method of one another activity from another activity

Tags: java, android

Here is the code snippet,

class1.java

```
public class1 extends ListActivity {


   public class1(){}

   public testMethod()
   {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside Method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

}
```

class2.java

```
public class2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          class1 c = new class1();
          c.testMethod();

    }

}
```

I want to call "testMethod" from class2, Currently it is giving following error,

```
08-04 22:59:27.428: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 22:59:27.428: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.assistant/com.assistant.AssistantActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.assistant/com.assistant.addNew}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks.

I have two tabs,

Tab1 extends Activity (class2.java) => Contains form to add entry in DB

Tab2 extends ListActivity (class1.java) => Contains list of the added entries

I want to refresh the Tab2 whenever any entry is added through Tab1 and I have added method in class2.java to fill the list with updated DB entries.

Now, I want to call that method from class1.java after the entry is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solution, wrote the code in "onResume()" of second tab, so no need to call method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making that method a static method.
Although I'm not sure if you are allowed to instantiate an Activity like that, did you remember to add them both to the Android manifest?

Perhaps `getApplicationContext()` is returning `null`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using static method, but in the method I have to use some instance attributes, So can't use static method for this case. Otherwise, it's nice solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`testMethod` needs a return type (such as void):

```
public void testMethod(){
   //your code
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have added void return type, but still same error occurs.